# Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I upgraded angular from v11 to v12. I am getting this error and I dont know why. there are no changes in build configuration or tsconfig.

Comment: We can't help you just with a message error. Please provide some code examples and explain better what you already tried and what you want to achieve.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 48):

Simple example

Wrong
`import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/';`

Correct
`import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';`

I faced this issue during a migration. Search for something similar in your code to fix the issue. In my case the component causing the issue was mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 10):

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http/';`

just remove **/** from last of your import as **[Thomas Renger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69507476/1581050)** mentioned above.

*like this*

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

Answer (score 6):

Check your imports, you may find a path that ends with a '/', just remove it and it will work!