# Getting Module not found error when upgrade angular v12 to v13

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi developers and contributors,

I am struggling to find out what is the issue with the following error:

> ./src/app/models/type/ModelType.ts:2:0-44 - Error: Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)

This error came when I upgraded my angular version from v12 to v13 (also upgraded some older packages with the latest ones). I am trying to solve this for a couple of days and it would be nice if someone faced the same issue, or have any ideas where it may come from.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446231/module-not-found-error-resolving-to-directories-is-not-possible-with-the-expor)? Could it be that you have a similar error in your file?
If not, please post more details (e.g. your ModelType.ts) because it's hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: Great, this was the problem in my case, too. Not exactly with the rxjs, but all the imports that have been ending with '/', e.g.,

>import { Injectable } from '@angular/core/';
In addition, I pasted the exact error and I could not find the question that you suggested. Since, your answer is just a comment, I cannot mark it as accepted in order to thank you. Do you have any clue why and how I can mark it?

Comment: In addition, now I have the following error:
> Uncaught TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.__decorate) is not a function
    at Module.2200 (app.service.ts:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.5921 (material.module.ts:62)
    ...

I found this question - https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/499455/uncaught-typeerror-0-tslib-webpack-imported-module-2-decorate-is-not-a , but there is no answer yet.

Comment: I suggest you raise a new question for this ohne. And in this question, please provice a bit more detail (e.g. the content of app.service.ts)

Comment: @AljoshaKoecher, thanks for the suggestions! It was a good idea to post the content of the package.json file (I suppose you meant this). Whatever, everything works fine now when I updated the typescript version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to "typescript": "4.5.4" resolved this issue.