# Uncaught TypeError after upgrading Angular v12 to v13

Tags: angular, typescript

I am struggling with the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.__decorate) is not a function
    at Module.2200 (app.service.ts:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.5921 (material.module.ts:62)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.3259 (app.module.ts:125)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.3696 (main.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.4750 (app.component.ts:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

This happened after I upgraded from v12 to v13. I already had other issues, which I fixed, like - [Getting Module not found error when upgrade angular v12 to v13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70236325/getting-module-not-found-error-when-upgrade-angular-v12-to-v13?noredirect=1#comment124171118_70236325).

This is how my app.service.ts file looks like - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3siaqz?file=src/app/app.service.ts, and the error is [Uncaught TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrFlO.png)

Comment: I had a look at your previous question and current question. Code you have pasted in stackblitz is not app.service.ts . it has AppComponent code. And also why you have imported like "../../node_modules" you should do that. ng update will change all ur imports to updated strings.

Comment: Hi @vaibhav,
When I open the link, I can see the correct file. About the imports, I just did it like this in order to try to solve the issue. I saw somewhere on the Internet that some imports which are not with implicitly specified path, they might get wrong. However, it did not fix the issue, but I kept it like this.

Comment: you can use slackblitz angular web container to replicate your error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcontainer-template-era8cj

Comment: Amm, the link that I provided is exactly from stackblitz, isn't it? Also, I cannot push the whole project there, because it is a private one. I tried to create a fresh app on stackblitz and to replicate the same error, but I could not be able to make it.

Comment: The link you have provided is using angular version 12. by using web container, you can perform all operations like ng update.

Comment: Okay, I did it, but the only thing that I wanted with the stackblitz is to show the code in my app.service.ts file, because I cannot paste the code here, since it takes more characters than the allowed ones.

Comment: Run `npm cache clean` and try to reinstall your node modules.

Comment: @need_to_know_now unfortunately does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to fix it when deleting not only the node_modules, but also the package-lock.json file, then I updated the npm version to the latest one (probably not needed) and ran:

```
npm install –legacy-peer-deps
```

Then the app was working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete your **node.js** file and reinstall

Comment: Do you mean to reinstall the Node.js? I already uninstall the Node and installed version 16.13.1, but nothing changes, except the warning that it was giving me for odd node version.

Comment: What is a node.js file? Pease update your answer, otherwise, I need to report that as an invalid answer ...