# FormGroup causes an error in compile that makes no sense

Tags: typescript, angular13

So, I have a form that works great.  But, I'm building another one and the VERY SAME BASE code is throwing this error:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/app/components/form-21a/form-21a.component.ts 3:0-57

Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)
```

This ONLY occurs when I do this...

```
    this.form21a = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl('')
    }, { updateOn: "blur" });
```

this.form21a is declared like so

```
  // Form Group Initalization
  vaform21!: FormGroup;
```

This is crazy as I'm doing the exact same thing with form21 in another component. The Code is SOUND.

When I remove

```
    this.form21a = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl('')
    }, { updateOn: "blur" });
```

The above error goes away.

here's my HTML

```
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 colNameOffset">
                          <label for="lastname" class="labels labelOverride">{{enumProps.LASTNAME}}</label>
                          <input #lastName type="text" id="lastname" class="form-control" name="lastname"
                            data-title="Last Name" required formControlName="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"
                            maxlength="75" (blur)="blurEventMethod($event)"
                            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ontabout && f['lastname'].errors }" />
                          <div *ngIf="submitted || f['lastname'].errors" class="required requiredAdjustA">
                            <span class="text-danger required">{{getErrorMessage('lastname', 'Last Name ')}}</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="firstname" class="labels labelOverride">{{enumProps.FIRSTNAME}}</label>
                        <input #firstname type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" name="firstname"
                          data-title="First Name" required formControlName="firstname" placeholder="First Name"
                          maxlength="35" (blur)="blurEventMethod($event)"
                          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ontabout && f['firstname'].errors }" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted || f['firstname'].errors" class="required requiredAdjustA">
                          <span class="text-danger required">{{getErrorMessage('firstname', 'First Name ')}}</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Here's how I declare the form

```
<form id="form21a" ngForm #Form21a [formGroup]="form21a (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form21a, $event)">
```

This is the EXACT same set up for form21.

in the DEV console I'm getting this...

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

      Example:

      
  <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
    <input formControlName="firstName">
  </div>

  In your class:

  this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl()
  });
```

What is NOT happening is that form21a is UNDEFINED. For some reason, this is working great in form21.  It's the same exact code. this.form21a is undefined when I put my mouse over it in the debug console but yet, form21a: FormGroup; is at the VERY TOP under the export line in the code.

NOTE:
Even doing this:

```
  // Form Group Initalization
  Form21A: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl(''),
    lastname: new FormControl('')
  });
```

Changing the cases of the form21a to Form21A still causes the above error...

Removing FORMGROUP, it compiles fine.

What is the problem?

UPDATE: Component File Imports

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Inject, Input, NgZone, OnInit, Output, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms/';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Form21elementService } from 'src/app/services/Form21.element.service';
import { DischargeTypes, ServiceBranch, Suffixes, VaForm21FieldsInstLabels } from '../form-21/Form21.enum';
import { Form21aFieldsInstLabels } from './Form21a.enum';
import * as data from 'src/assets/json/disclaimers.json';
import * as orgs from 'src/assets/json/orgs.json';
import * as agnt from 'src/assets/json/agents.json';
import * as epts from 'src/assets/json/dept.json';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { CrudService } from 'src/app/service/crud.service';
import { Regx } from 'src/app/enums-interfaces/regx';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad';
import { PhoneNumberInputFormatService } from 'src/app/services/phone-number-import-format.service';
import { APIS } from 'src/environments/env-service.service';
import { CommonSvcsService } from 'src/app/services/common-svcs.service';
import { SessionStorageService } from 'angular-web-storage';
import { ModalService } from 'src/app/services/modal.service';
import { Form21Fields, Form21Section2 } from 'src/app/components/form-21/Form21.interface';
```

I'm sharing common stuff between form21a and form21.

OMG I think I just found it!
import { VaForm21aFieldsInstLabels } from './Form21a.enum';

Has that ./ Darn, let me fix and give it another try

That didn't fix it but the only thing let is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-21a',
  templateUrl: './form-21a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-21a.component.scss']
})
```

You can't fully qualify those as it errors out and says, can't find template or scss

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't closing the `formGroup` attribute value correctly when you declare your form in the template. You need to close the attribute value with another set of quotes before declaring the `ngSubmit` attribute.

i.e.,

```
<form 
    id="form21a" 
    ngForm #Form21a 
    [formGroup]="form21a" <-- This attribute needs to be closed properly.
    (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form21a, $event)"
>
```

**Edit with solution to module error:**

The reason you are seeing the

```
Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)
```

error is because you are importing with a trailing slash.

If you remove the trailing slash from the import

```
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms/';
```

it should resolve the error.

See: [Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446231/module-not-found-error-resolving-to-directories-is-not-possible-with-the-expor)

Comment: I fixed that, still getting the error: ./src/app/components/form-21a/form-21a.component.ts:3:0-57 - Error: Module not found: Error: Resolving to directories is not possible with the exports field (request was ./)

Comment: also, form21: FormGroup is always UNDEFINED... even when I do this: this.form21 = new FormGroup({ ... });  This make absolutely no sense as form21, it's sibling, uses the same code (to a point) and there's never been a problem

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude, can you post the component file's imports.

Comment: After fixing "two" ./ and ../ I'm still getting request was ./

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude Looks like it could be the import line `import { AbstractControl, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms/';` Try removing the final '/' at the end of '@angular/forms/'

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE! That compiled. OMG! Thank you